# Why RecyclerView with nestedScrollView pagination slow down application?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-recyclerview, pagination

I'm implementing pagination in recyclerview, it slow down when some products load into recyclerview and on some devices ( like samsung s6 ) it crashes.

NOTE:
App slow down if Recyclerview is under nestedScrollview, otherwise it works well.

I've tested almost all the solution I search on internet, but could be able to solve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView

        android:id="@+id/containers_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--image slider-->
            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/vf_slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/_200dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <include

                android:id="@+id/recommendation_container_parent"
                layout="@layout/reccomendation_products_layout"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pb_product_load"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/brands_in_focus_container" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

```
adapter = new ProductAdapter(getContext(), this);
    adapter.setData(productList);
    fragment.recommendationContainerParent.rvRecommendedProducts.setAdapter(recommendationProductAdapter);
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);


    fragment.recommendationContainerParent.rvRecommendedProducts.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        fragment.recommendationContainerParent.rvRecommendedProducts.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    } else {
        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(fragment.recommendationContainerParent.rvRecommendedProducts, false);
    }

    fragment.containersParent.setOnScrollChangeListener((NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener) (v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY) -> {
        if (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
            if ((scrollY >= (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) &&
                    scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                //code to fetch more data for endless scrolling


                if (!isLoading) {


                    isLoading = true;

                    parameters.clear();

                    INITIAL_INDEX = END_INDEX;
                    INITIAL_INDEX++; // starting from end+1
                    END_INDEX += NUMBER_OF_ITEM;

                    parameters.put(START_INDEX, String.valueOf(INITIAL_INDEX));
                    parameters.put(LENGTH, String.valueOf(NUMBER_OF_ITEM));

                    getProductItems();
                }

            }

        }
    });

    void getProductItems() {

    parameters.put(RECOMMENDED_CAT_TOKEN, recommended_cat);

    homeViewModel.getRecommendations(parameters).observe(this, productContainer -> {

        if (productContainer != null && productContainer.getProductData().getProducts().size() > 0) {

            productList.addAll(productContainer.getProductData().getProducts());
            recommendationProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            isLoading = false;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Which error you got while crash on s6?

Comment: _parameters_ stands for? Also need to post crash log

Comment: Also you need to set `recyclerview.setNestedScrolling(false)` for Recyclerview.

Comment: @AjayPandya Logcat does not show any error. but my primary concern is to make scroll smoothly

Comment: @Piyush parameters are for retrofit call for more items (pagination).

Comment: But it should be already in _getProductItems()_ function. Have you done this _recyclerview.setNestedScrolling(false)_?

Comment: @Piyush yes I have set this boolean, you can see above.

Comment: Are you using live data ??  If so then you should use [this](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-recyclerview-pagination-with-paging-library-using-mvvm-rxjava-dagger-2-and-livedata-b0489ecbbfc0)

Comment: @RimshaButt Have you solved?

Comment: @Piyush I need to solve the problem but you suggested me to change my app flow thats not possible for me right now

Comment: Yes. That could not be! But recyclerview getting slow and lagging because of nested scrollview. Because code seems ok. Have you tried to move  _parameters.put(START_INDEX, String.valueOf(INITIAL_INDEX));
                    parameters.put(LENGTH, String.valueOf(NUMBER_OF_ITEM));_ in _getProductItems()_?

Comment: yes, I have tried it, but it was not working